# ¿Cómo podría crear un array mas simple partiendo de el siguiente codigo?

Tags: javascript, array, código-de-barras

me hacen las siguientes recomendaciones: Es muy repetitiva y tediosa de escribir,No es genérica, sólo sirve para arrays de 6 elemento;si tiene más de seis elementos, sólo suma los primeros
Si tiene menos no funciona bien

este es la funcion que creado.

```
function sumatoriaGananciasSemestre(unSemestre) {
    return unSemestre[0] + unSemestre[1] +
        unSemestre[2] + unSemestre[3] +
        unSemestre[4] + unSemestre[5];
        }
        console.log(sumatoriaGananciasSemestre)
```

Answer (score 2):

proba usando [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)  con un valor inicial de 0

```
unSemestre.reduce( ( a, b ) => a + b, 0 );
```

```js
function gananciaSemestre(unSem) {
  return unSem.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

unSemestre = [10, 15, 11, 0, 3, 1 ,2];
console.log(gananciaSemestre(unSemestre));
console.log(gananciaSemestre([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(gananciaSemestre([]));
```